# how do I customize the form values in django admin to show only those values that are assigned to him/her?

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, django-forms

I have  implemented row level permission in my django admin application.I have my three models which are:

1. **Course**-- {Title, code}
2. **Unit** -- {Title, Course(foreign key)}
3. **Topic**-- {Title, Unit(foreign key)}

Note: (Words above in bold are model names and values in curly braces are field for each model)

Every user has permission to add/edit/delete particular courses that are assigned to him/her. I am using `def queryset(self, request):` method to check which user has permission for which courses and then return a queryset with those courses. By that way I m able to display user particular courses assigned to him/her.

A **course** can have many Units and further a Unit can have many Topics.Its a hierarchy.

So I am using again same `def queryset(self, request):` for filtering Units and Topics to show only that Units and Topic that comes under course assigned to him/her. Till now everything goes well like user is able to see only those **Units** and **topics** which are related to his/her **course**. But when user tries to edit a unit a form appears with two fields:

1. **Title** (title of unit that he can rename)
2. **course** (Drop-down list of all courses from which he can choose anyone /foreign key)

In second field **"course"** drop-down I just want user to be able to see only those courses that are assigned to him/her.so that he/she would not be able to update the Unit with any other course that is not assigned to him/her.

Same case is with while editing **Topics**, a user can see all the Units in drop-down field and can select any unit for the topic.

I think I need to override some view or do some magic, but can't find out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably override the `formfield_for_foreignkey` method in your `ModelAdmin` for `Unit` to alter the queryset based on the request. Something like (untested):

```
class UnitAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request=None, **kwargs):
        if db_field.name == 'course':
            # filter queryset somehow based on request.user:
            kwargs['queryset'] = db_field.rel.to._default_manager.filter(...) 
        return super(
            UnitAdmin, self).formfield_for_foreignkey(db_field, request, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [django-smart-select](https://github.com/digi604/django-smart-selects)

```
from smart_selects.db_fields import ChainedForeignKey
```

example code

```
from django.db import models
from smart_selects.db_fields import ChainedForeignKey

class Continent(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Country(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    continent=models.ForeignKey(Continent)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Area(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    country=models.ForeignKey(Country)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Location(models.Model):
    continent = models.ForeignKey(Continent)
    country = ChainedForeignKey(
        Country, 
        chained_field="continent",
        chained_model_field="continent", 
        show_all=False, 
        auto_choose=True
    )
    area = ChainedForeignKey(Area, chained_field="country", chained_model_field="country")
    city = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    street = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def get_products(self):
        return ','.join([p.name for p in self.area.all()])
```